# Migrate Domain from Server 2008 R2 to Small Business Server 2011

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, migration, windows-sbs

I'm looking for some advice here, rather than the big *how to do it* I'm looking for *what do to*

I have this home server, quad core and 4 GB of ram (I really can't afford more right now). With a Windows Serve 2008 R2 With ActiveDirectory and a Hyper-V-Virtual machine with SharePoint, TFS and a couple of more thigs.

I have a least 10 remote users, all of them joined a Hamachi VPN (working great by the way). But I want to migrate that to a Small Business Server 2011 Standard.

I tried to make a VM to join the domain and then promote that VM, back up it and then format the physical server, boot up the VM, Promote the Phisical and then erase the VM, but I can't do that because of SBS requiring a least 4 GB of ram to install (so I can't give all the 4 GB of physical ram to a VM).

I was thinking in using a laptop (All the clients are laptop) as a temporal server, join the domain, promote it, then format the server and install SBS on the server and do all again.

I really need some advice. Thanks in advance.

BTW, I know that the software I'm using is kindda expensive, and I can't afford more hardware. I have access to MS downloads by a University partnership so I have all this software for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst SBS has a minimum memory requirement of 4GB RAM, you may find that you have resource issues if that is the maximum amount of RAM you have, particularly if your users are going to be heavy Exchange users.

That said, if you want to format that machine so you can put SBS on it, you will need to setup a temporary domain controller to contain your domain while you transition. So your laptop solution should work, assuming you don't have a heave load on it. You will want to ensure you leave enough time fore AD to replicate before you decommission the old DC.

Once you have the SBS server on the domain, you will need to make sure that the SBS server meets the licence requirements within 14 days:
 - SBS Must hold all the FSMO roles
 - SBS Must be a Global Catalog Server

Comment: Nice, thank you. But I was wondering another thing, but prefer to ask another question: http://serverfault.com/questions/228351/quick-one-better-environment-for-exchange-2010-server-2008-r2-or-sbs-2011-stand